# get unique call details from CallLog

Tags: android

I am trying to access  call logs in android application , here i am getting all call details but i want unique call details only , i don't want repeated values.

is there any way to get unique call log details in android ?

Comment: can you post your full code for getting all call details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all call details and add them in `Set`. Set does not allow dupes.

Idea and guess: 
If you are extracting each detail differently you might find easier to use `Map` and then add the `keySet()` to the `Set` data and then again you populate the map.
Remember in CallLog you might find same key (let's say Contact name) but different data for that call (Time, duration etc etc).